# Differential of group action on quotient of Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have the following (possibly silly) question. Let $G$ be a Lie group, in particular a matrix Lie group such as $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$. Let $\Gamma\subset G$ be a discrete subgroup, which acts on $G$ via left multiplication. Let $K$ denote "the" maximal compact subgroup of $G$ (in case $G=Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$, $K=U(n)$) which acts on $G$ via right multiplication. We can form the quotient $G/K$, and this inherits the left action of $\Gamma$. What is the differential/derivative of the left action of $\Gamma$ on $G/K$? Is it just left multiplication on the Lie algebra of $G/K$? If I'm not wrong, the tangent space at any point of $G/K$ can be identified with $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{k}$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{k}$ denote Lie algebras of $G$ and $K$ respectively. Why should left multiplication by elements of $\Gamma$ preserve $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{k}$?

Follow up qustion: Does the action of $\Gamma$ on $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{k}$ commute with the adjoint action of $K$ on $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{k}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Differentiating an action requires that action to be from a group with some notion of differentiating (e.g. a Lie group). A discrete group doesn't have this, even one that is contained in a Lie group.

Comment: It does of course have an action on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ by restriction but this does not descend to an action on $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{k}$ unless the action preserves $\mathfrak{k}$. I don't think there is any reason in general why this action (if it exists) would commute with the action of $K$.

Comment: consider the following situation: $G/K$ is a manifold, and the group $G$ acts on it via automorphisms (e.g. $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/U(1)$ is the upper half space). Now if I take the quotient of $G/K$ by a discrete cocompact subgroup $\Gamma\subset G$, then I get a curve? The fundamental group of the curve is isomorphic to $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ acts on $G/K$ via deck transformations, so it should also act on the tangent spaces of $G/K$ yes?

Comment: Acting on a manifold doesn't give you an action on tangent spaces. It may give you an action on the tangent bundle as a whole but it doesn't preserve the individual fibres as a general rule.

Comment: The map $x\mapsto gx$ induces a map of tangent spaces $\mathcal{T}_x\to\mathcal{T}_{gx}$ for $g\in\Gamma$ right? How does one determine where an element $f\in\mathcal{T}_x$ is mapped to in $\mathcal{T}_{gx}$? Is this map equivariant under the adjoint action of $K$ on tangent spaces? Thanks for your comments btw!

Comment: So the map is easy to define: $X + \mathfrak{k} \in \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{k}$ gets sent to $gX + g\mathfrak{k} \in \mathfrak{g}/g\mathfrak{k}$ where this is just the usual adjoint action on $\mathfrak{g}$. It isn't equivariant with respect to $K$ however. Indeed $K$ doesn't have an action on each tangent space. It preserves $\mathfrak{k}$ and so has an action on $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{k}$ but not on other tangent spaces. $g\circ k$ sends $\mathfrak{k}$ to $g\mathfrak{k}$ but $k\circ g$ sends it to $(g\mathfrak{k})k$ which is a different space whenever $g$ doesn't preserve $\mathfrak{k}$.

Comment: I see, this was very helpful. Thanks again!